# MVVM button disabling

Tags: silverlight

I am using SIlverLight RelayCommand to enable and disable buttons. 
Based on some condition i want to disable a button , 
Please suggest how can i disable a button

Below is working fine for initial load,

```
 public RelayCommand BackClickCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_backClickCommand == null)
            {
                _backClickCommand = new RelayCommand(() =>
                {
                    step--;
                    if(step<1)
                   // code need to diable this button
                }, () => this.CanExecute());
            }

            return _backClickCommand;

        }
    }
    int step=2;

    public bool CanExecute()
    {
        if(step>0)
        return enabled;
        else false;
    }
```

Some where in my code i am doing

```
    enabled = false;
```

Please suggest how can i disable my button

Thanks,

Comment: Hi user1814841, if you've found an answer to be a fix to your problem, please mark it a such. If not, and you've fixed it yourself, you can answer your own question. See the faq for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're binding your Xaml like this:

```
<Button Command="{Binding BackClickCommand}" />
```

All you need to do is remind the UI to check the binding again:

```
enabled = false;
PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("BackClickCommand"));
```

This will make the UI check the `BackClickCommand` again and see it's changed, thus disabling the button.

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) for a full code example.

Edit: this would be a possible piece of code:

```
int step = 2;

public RelayCommand BackClickCommand
{
    get
    {
        if (_backClickCommand == null)
        {
            _backClickCommand = new RelayCommand(() =>
            {
                step--;
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("BackClickCommand")); 
            }, () => this.CanExecute());
        }

        return _backClickCommand;

    }
}

public bool CanExecute()
{
    return this.step > 0;
}
```

Comment: sorry for confusion just added more , code i want to disable button based on the integer Step value. Please suhggest

Answer (score 0):

Whenever the step value changes, you have to notify the command has changed so CanExecute is evaluated again.

As you said, enabled will be evaluated somewhere in the code.

Your code can be more less the same:

```
int step=2;

public RelayCommand BackClickCommand
{
    get
    {
        if (_backClickCommand == null)
        {
            _backClickCommand = new RelayCommand(() =>
            {
                step--; // Your logic
                OnPropertyChanged("BackClickCommand"); // Notify the change!
            }, () => this.CanExecute());
        }

        return _backClickCommand;
    }
}

public bool CanExecute()
{
    return enabled;
}
```

Comment: I am using Galasoft RaisePropertyChanged it is not firing. Any issue with RaisePropertyChanged?

Comment: Working fine with .RaiseCanExecuteChanged();